# JetBrains IDE remove indexing non-relevant folders

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

[image]

Hello everyone. How can I set up searching into project to avoid searching into these build or public folders to reduced non-relevant data

Comment: Please make sure to mark the `build` folder excluded (**Mark directory as/Excluded**) - this should improve the searching experience (as well as navigation and performance - build target folders are changed too often causing re-indexing)

Comment: @lena I've done this but in search I've still seen them, is it okay?

Comment: No, it's not; files from excluded folders are not indexed and don't normally appear in search results